# Filter mysql query by duplicates and row count

Tags: mysql

Task is to get list of ordercodes where there are more than 2 different specialcode,
now i am already have this query

```
SELECT
    o.id        AS iOrderId,
    o.code          AS sOrderCode,
    oa.pnr          AS sSpecialCode
FROM
    order_air AS oa
JOIN
    orders AS o ON 1
        AND oa.order_id = o.id
WHERE 1 
    AND o.status = 11
    AND oa.issued = 1
    AND oa.change_status != 0
    AND oa.issued_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
LIMIT 20
```

And it returns me

[image]

Everything is fine, but this query is not checking for different specialcodes and just returns all ordercodes where there more than 2 special codes.
I've tried too look into IF's to save previous orderid and then do checks by it, but i don't realize how to store previous id into something like @prev , so this not helped me, any ideas how to filter this queue right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you're trying to do.

```
SELECT
    o.id        AS iOrderId,
    o.code      AS sOrderCode
FROM
    orders AS o
JOIN
    (SELECT order_id, COUNT(DISTINCT pnr) AS cnt
     FROM order_air
     WHERE issued = 1
       AND change_status != 0
       AND issued_date BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH AND NOW()
     GROUP BY order_id) oa_count
ON o.id = oa_count.order_id

WHERE oa_count.cnt >= 2 
  AND o.status = 11

LIMIT 20
```

Comment: No, your query returns iOrderId with all similar oa.pnr :) And the problem is to "where there are more than 2 **different** specialcode"

Comment: I've just updated the answer to only count distinct `pnr`s. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

```
JOIN
orders AS o ON 1
    AND oa.order_id = o.id
    AND something < something else
```

Comment: Any explanation for **something** ?